# Finding the machine value of epsilon in Matlab

Tags: matlab, numeric, approximation

The following Matlab code is meant to find the machine value of epsilon.

```
e = 1; 
while (1+e>1) 
    if e+1 <= 1
        e = 2*e;
    else e = e/2; 
    end
end
e = 2*e
```

While the value of epsilon is correctly approximated, modifying the code leads to unexpected results. For example, if the while loop condition is modified, as shown below, to e>0 the program either crashes or outputs 0 rather than an approximation for epsilon even though adding a constant doesn't change the inequality. Could someone explain why this is happening?

```
e = 1; 
while (e>0) 
    if e+1 <= 1
        e = 2*e;
    else e = e/2; 
    end
end
e=2*e
```

Comment: Are you aware of the [`eps`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eps.html) function? Regarding why your code doesn't work: your premise that adding a constant doesn't change the inequality is not correct, due to numerical inaccuracies. Compare `1+1e-20>1` and `1e-20>0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The concept of “epsilon” is that there is a minimal value that must be added to 1 to obtain a different value. If `e` is smaller than epsilon, then `1+e==1`. Floating-point numbers cannot represent values in between 1 and 1 + epsilon.

So replacing the condition in the while loop, `1+e>1`, with `e>0`, though mathematically equivalent, breaks the concept we are trying to define: epsilon as the smallest value to add to 1 to get a value larger from 1. Note that you can represent values very close to 0, such as 10<sup>-300</sup>, but you cannot represent values that close to 1. Epsilon is about 10<sup>-16</sup>. This means that the two inequalities are not the same when working with floating-point numbers.

---

Note that the statement `if e+1 <= 1` is only reached when `1+e>1`, and so will always be false. You can simplify the code by removing this if statement and keeping only the code in the `else` clause:

```matlab
e = 1;
while 1+e > 1
   e = e/2;
end
e = 2*e
```